# Yeoman - How to extract zipped files in generator?

Tags: yeoman, yeoman-generator

I want to build a Yeoman generator that needs to unzip a file.

From their [documentation](http://yeoman.io/authoring/file-system.html), it seems this process is done using `this.registerTransformStream(...)`. It says it accept any gulp plugin, so I tried `gulp-unzip` ([link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-unzip))

Here's my code:

```
// index.js
...
writing: function() {
  var source = this.templatePath('zip'); // the folder where the zipped file is
  var destination = this.destinationRoot();

  this.fs.copy(source, destination);
  this.registerTransformStream(unzip() );
}
...
```

The result seems promising, first it shows all the file list then I get `Error: write after end` error.

Here's the dump:

```
   create license.txt
   create readme.html
   create config.php
   ...
   ...
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: write after end
    at writeAfterEnd (C:\Users\myname\Documents\project\generator-test\node_modules\gulp-unzip\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:144:12)
    at Transform.Writable.write (C:\Users\myname\Documents\project\generator-test\node_modules\gulp-unzip\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:192:5)
    at DestroyableTransform.ondata (C:\Users\myname\Documents\project\generator-test\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:531:20)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at DestroyableTransform.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at readableAddChunk (C:\Users\myname\Documents\project\generator-test\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:198:18)
    at DestroyableTransform.Readable.push (C:\Users\myname\Documents\project\generator-test\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:157:10)
    at DestroyableTransform.Transform.push (C:\Users\myname\Documents\project\generator-test\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_transform.js:123:32)
    at DestroyableTransform._transform (C:\Users\myname\Documents\project\generator-test\node_modules\mem-fs-editor\lib\actions\commit.js:34:12)
    at DestroyableTransform.Transform._read (C:\Users\myname\Documents\project\generator-test\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_transform.js:159:10)
```

The destination folder **is empty** after this. It seems the stream is trying to write the unzipped file but failed.

Does anyone solved this problem before? Or is there **alternative way by just using the built-in** `fs`?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Personally, I think it would be easier for you to manually unzip the file using a Node.js package. Yeoman is only javascript code running, so no need to find a Yeoman related helper. Any node code will works inside the generator framework.

Comment: @SimonBoudrias Sorry for the late reply. Yeoman uses `mem-fs`, so the zip file doesn't exist until all finished. I can't find a way to target that file using something like `node-unzip` since `mem-fs` doesn't seem to have callback too.

Comment: no need to copy the zip file with mem-fs if you just want to unzip the content.

Comment: @SimonBoudrias I finally found a way to still use the built-in copy. We can add callback by using [commit](https://github.com/SBoudrias/mem-fs-editor#commitfilters-callback). Inside the callback, I unzip it with `adm-zip` package. Thanks for your input :). I can give you the bounty if you want. Just put answer mentioning that.